# Name first on car loan can you also be the cosigner

Tags: loans, car

If a name is first on a car loan does that mean he is the primary and not a cosigner. OR can you be first on car loan and still be the cosigner

Comment: Depending on where you are, there may be no such thing as a "primary" or "secondary" borrower on a car loan.  Can you explain what you think it means to be "the primary" on a car loan?

Comment: The lender probably doesn't distinguish; typically, the only difference would be who gets title to the car once the loan is paid off, but that's not an issue the lender would care about.

Comment: This could really use a jurisdiction.  If US, state may matter as well.  I'm also a bit concerned by the change from primary to first.  Primary has legal meaning.  Perhaps the question was intended to be if the co-signer (second on the loan) could be named primary.  If so, that's obscured by the edit.  But as I don't know which is the correct interpretation, I'm not going to make things potentially worse with my own edit.

Answer (score 3):

I want to first state that I'm not an attorney and this is not a response that would be considered legal advice.  I'm going to assume this was a loan was made in the USA.  The OP didnt specify.

A typical auto loan has a borrower and the ability to add a co-borrower or "cosigner".  The first signer on the contract is considered the "primary".  As to your question about a primary being a co-borrower my answer would be no.  Primary simply means first signer and you can't be a first signer and a co-borrower.  Both borrower and co-borrower, unless the contract specifies different, are equally responsible for the auto loan regardless if you're a borrower or a co-borrower (primary or not primary).

I'm not sure if there was a situation not specified that prompted the question.  Just remember that when you add a co-borrower their positive and negative financials are handled equally as the borrower.  So in some cases a co-borrower can make the loan not qualify.

(I worked for an auto finance company for 16 years)